# How to resolve language file URL for Jquery datatables in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, datatables

In my ASP.NET app I am using Jquery datatables plugin like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#grdData').DataTable({
          "language": { "url": "Scripts/json/table-language.json" }
      });
   </script>
```

when running this on localhost it works fine and it fetches the json file.
But in production I get a 404 not found error.
I guess it somehow relates to relative path...
any ideas on how to fix the path so it would work?

Comment: "/Scripts/json/table-language.json" try this instead

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
It was related to IIS, I needed to add Mime Type of .json extension and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Can use way '../data/dataTables/german.json'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).