# DataTables json language file on asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a web application asp.net mvc. In this application, I use DataTables that I configure like that to have the french language:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('table#list').DataTable({
            'language': {
                'url': '@Url.Content("~/Content/datatables-i18n.fr.json")'
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

When I test my application locally, it works, I have the datatable in French but when I publish my application (with Visual Studio), it's not working anymore. I have this error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

But if I pass the cdn url instead of my file, it works locally and also after publishing :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var table;
    $(function () {
        table = $('table#list').DataTable({
            language: {
                'url': 'http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/French.json'
            }
      })
</script>
```

Do you know why the file is not find after publishing ?

Comment: Hi, maybe it's an obviouse question but are you positive that Visual Studio is publishing your localized files (I'm talking about solution explorer -> properties of the /Content/datatables-i18n.fr.json -> copy in output folder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Url.Content` working properly on local but not in production (publish) & you're sure the file exists on the corresponding folder (i.e. `[application folder]\Content`), possibly it related to registered IIS file type issue. You can add `json` MIME type to the IIS using these steps:

1) Select your site in `Sites` section, choose `MIME Types` option in IIS category.

2) Use `Add` to show "Add MIME Type" box.

3) Add proper MIME type for JSON file extension as `application/json` as shown in this image, then click OK (possible requires restarting your site to apply this change):

[image]

If both local & production environment returning 404 for `Url.Content` path, it is possible that the problem originated from browser security issue, since [`language`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) configuration options require AJAX callback and some browsers disallow AJAX request to retrieve local files by using `file://` path ([more info](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32970/datatable-language-url-doesnt-work-for-local-files)). When this becomes your current issue, nothing else than using DataTables CDN URL like `http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/French.json` since you can't control client's browser security settings.

Similar issues:

[How to resolve language file URL for Jquery datatables in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410341/how-to-resolve-language-file-url-for-jquery-datatables-in-asp-net)

[how to change language for DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342494/how-to-change-language-for-datatable)

Comment: Yes, thanks, it was a problem of MIME type. I just added this line  "<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />" in the web.config file under "<system.webServer> <staticContent>".